# Is it true that $a_1^2a_2^2+a_2^2a_3^2+\cdots+a_8^2a_1^2 \leq 8$ if $a_1^3+a_2^3+\cdots+a_8^3=8 $ for positive numbers?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

As in the title

> Is it true that $a_1^2a_2^2+a_2^2a_3^2+\cdots+a_8^2a_1^2 \leq 8$ if $a_1^3+a_2^3+\cdots+a_8^3=8    $  for positive numbers?

I'm not sure how to answer it. I've got some conclusion but those do not help, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have been your conclusions and what is the source or the problem?

Comment: @PierreCarre No, because the statement would be false with $a_i=1$ for all $i$.

Comment: @VIVID Once in question appears "for positive numbers" I instantly think of trying inequalities between means. Also, of course, every $a_i$ is less than two. Source: https://omj.edu.pl/uploads/attachments/om2017-tresci.pdf

Comment: My initial though was Holder’s inequality, because of the different exponents, but I couldn’t get that to work.

Comment: There is an elementary proof, namely they provided an explicit counterexample to the inequality. What else are you asking for?

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, but it was obtained by not that elementary tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is that big jumps are bad - in particular jumping from above 1 to below 1.

The simplest way to achieve this is $(1,x,x,x,1,y,y,y)$ where $x^3+y^3=2$ and $x\neq 1$. We need to maximize $2x^4+2x^2 + 2y^4+2y^2$. By AMGM, when $x\neq 1$, $2x^4+2x^2> 4x^3$, so $2x^4+2x^2 + 2y^4+2y^2>4x^3+4y^3=8$ giving the desired elementary counterexample.

Answer (score 5):

The inequality does not hold. Try
$$a = (0.150104,0.560857,1.0906,1.429,1.37785,0.967096,0.437358,0.0989485).$$

I obtained this vector as one of the candidates to min/max coming from the Lagrange multipliers method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I am sure there is more elementary approach for that statement since this question is supposed to be for middle/high schoolers.

Comment: @1qwertyyy I agree. Either there is an elementary approach or it is a very badly conceived question. But that can happen sometimes...

Comment: What do you mean by "badly conceived"?

Comment: @1qwertyyyy If a problem is conceived for a certain set of students but cannot be solved with the tools available to them, it was not properly designed.

Comment: Oh. It is more of olympiad type of question. So I guess that students attempting to solve this problem should figure it out by themselves without using any formulaic methods.

Comment: @1qwertyyyy I see... I guess students could try to solve simpler problems where they fix some of the variables and play with the others. For instance, if you set $a_1=a_2=a_3=a_4=1.1$ and $a_5=a_6=a_7=0.8$, you can compute $a_8$ such that the restriction is satisfied and observe that $f(a)>8$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$f(x,y,z)=x^2y^2+y^2z^2+z^2x^2,\tag1$$
$$F(\overrightarrow a) = a_1^2a_2^2+a_2^2a_3^2+a_3^2a_4^2+\dots+a_8^2a_1^2,$$
then
$$F(\overrightarrow a) = f(a_8,a_1,a_2) + f(a_2,a_3,a_4) + f(a_4,a_5,a_6) + f(a_6,a_7,a_8) - (a_2^2+a_6^2)(a_4^2+a_8^2).$$
If $$a_4=a_8\to 0,\quad a_2=a_6 = p,\quad a_1=a_3=a_5=a_7=q,\tag2$$
then
$$F(\overrightarrow a) = 4p^2q^2\bigg|_{p^3+2q^3=4}=4\sqrt[3]4\,\left(q\sqrt[3]{2-q^3}\right)^2 = g(q),$$
where
$$g' = 8\sqrt[3]4q\left(\sqrt[3]{2-q^3}\right)^2\left(1-\dfrac{q^3}{2-q^3}\right) , $$
$$\max F(\overrightarrow a) = 8\sqrt[3]2\quad\text{at}\quad q=1,\quad p=\sqrt[\large3]2.\tag3$$

Therefore, the OP bound should be increased.

Comment: $4p^2q^2=4 *4^{1/3}$ when q is 1, p is $2^{1/3}$. I think there’s an error in your calc.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:

First, note that
$$\left(\frac{\sum a_i^2 a_{i+1}^2} { 8}\right) ^{1/2} \le \left(\frac{\sum a_i^3 a_{i+1}^3} { 8}\right) ^{1/3}$$

Now, it is enough to check that
$$\sum_{i=1}^8 a_i^3 a_{i+1}^3 \le 8$$
if $a_i$ are positive with  $\sum a_i^3 =1$, or, equivalently
$$\sum_{i=1}^8 b_i b_{i+1} \le 8$$

if $b_i$ are positive with sum $8$.  Now, it is enough to check that

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^ 8  x_i x_{i+1} }{ 8 } \le \left ( \frac{\sum x_i}{8} \right )^2 $$

for $x_i$ positive ( and say $\le 1$) .

$Added:$  It turns out that the last inequality is not correct, as @Martin R: pointed out.  It may work for some smaller values of $n$, but not $n=8$.

Now it seems that the original inequality is also not correct.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the last inequality does not hold for $x=(1, 1, 0, \ldots, 0)$: The LHS is $1/8$, and the RHS is $1/4^2$.

Comment: @Martin R: Yes, you are righ!  It's only true for a few small values of $n$, but not for $n=8$. Thanks for the input!

Comment: what is the first inequality called? some generalization of rms-am?

Comment: @kyary: It's the Jensen inequality for the convex function $x\mapsto x^{3/2}$, slightly disguised

Comment: @kyary: It is also known as [power mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Inequality_between_any_two_power_means)